# "Thunk" в контексте виртуальных функций

Tags: c++, терминология

Что такое "Thunk" в контексте виртуальных функций?(Как работает?)

Comment: Слишком мало деталей на мой взгляд

Comment: Этот вопрос вполне понятен и его расширять не нужно. Если кому-то не ясна его суть, то это не значит, что вопрос плохой.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В некоторых реализациях термин "thunk" означает "промежуточную вызывалку" для виртуальной функции. "Промежуточная вызывалка" может быть нужна тогда, когда для правильного вызова виртуального метода необходимо предварительно вычислить корректное значение указателя `this`, но способ этого вычисления зависит от контекста времени выполнения. Thunk также может использоваться для реализации корректной функциональности указателей на методы в ситуациях, когда такие указатели указывают на виртуальные методы.

Например

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : Base    
{
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "derived" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  void (Base::*ptr)() = &Base::foo; // 1

  Base b;
  (b.*ptr)();                       // 2

  Derived d;
  (d.*ptr)();                       // 3
}
```

В этом коде указатель `ptr` вроде бы "привязывается" к функции `Base::foo` в точке 1. Однако в ситуациях, когда `Base::foo` является виртуальной функцией, спецификация языка требует, чтобы решение о конкретной функции для вызова принималось не в точке инициализации (точка 1), а *в точке вызова* (то есть в точках 2 и 3) на основе анализа динамического типа объекта. В точке 2 должна быть вызвана `Base::foo`, а в точке 3 - `Derived::foo`.

Поэтому компилятор не может в точке 1 заставить указатель `ptr` указывать напрямую на `Base::foo`. Он вынужден использовать какой-то промежуточный код, который уже на основе анализа динамического типа объекта в точках 2 и 3 примет решение о том, какую же функцию надо вызвать в этом месте.

Одним из вариантов реализации такого механизма является заведение в классе `Base` скрытого невиртуального метода-"вызывалки", который внутри себя делает обычный виртуальный вызов метода `foo`. Указатель `ptr` ставится именно на этот скрытый метод

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }

  void foo_thunk() { foo(); }
};

...
void (Base::*ptr)() = &Base::foo;
// на самом деле транслируется в 
void (Base::*ptr)() = &Base::foo_thunk;
```

В результате мы получаем требуемое поведение при вызовах через `ptr` в точках 2 и 3. Т.е. в обоих случаях сначала вызывается именно `Base::foo_thunk`, а уже оттуда через обычный виртуальный механизм управление попадает в правильное `foo`.

Вот этот скрытый метод `foo_thunk` - это и есть так называемый "thunk". Таким способом реализует вызовы через указатели на виртуальные методы компилятор MSVC++. Компилятор GCC при компиляции вышеприведенного простейшего примера будет использовать иной подход (без thunk), но стоит ввести в пример множественное наследование, как в сгенерированном GCC коде тоже появятся thunks.

В том числе именно для поддержки такого подхода к реализации указателей на методы стандарт языка С++ [говорит](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#4.3), что результат сравнения двух указателей на методы не специфицирован, если хотя бы один из них указывает на виртуальный метод. Дело в том, что на низком уровне один и тот же thunk может переиспользоваться для обслуживания совершенно разных виртуальных методов. Т.е. устанавливая указатель на разные виртуальные методы вы можете тем не менее получить одно и то же физическое значение в указателе (указатель на один и тот же thunk).

Comment: Все вокруг  да около. ..  Можно  было бы ответить короче и понятней

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan; Можно было ответить "короче", но получилось бы "вокруг да около" и непонятно. Вот для того, чтобы избежать этого, я и написал очень *конкретный* ответ: понятный и без малейшего намека на  "вокруг да около".